# Why does my ng-class display even when false

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class, angular-ng-class

I have an image I'm trying to shake when a user guesses the name of a fish wrong. I'm using a conditional `ng-class="{'shake':error}"`. However, even when the answer is correct the image shakes. I don't believe that at anytime `$scope.error` is set to true. What am I missing here?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/TaylorN/pen/egdvGj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is `return` guessIsCorrect or guessIsWrong from your `compare` function.

```
$scope.compare = function(guess) {
    guess = guess.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
    var answers = [];
    answers.push($scope.name.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase());

    currentAnimal.alts.forEach(function(alt) {
        answers.push(alt.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''));
    });
    //console.log(answers);
    //console.log("Guess: " + guess + "\n");
    //console.log("Answer: " + answers + "\n");

    for (var x = 0; x <= answers.length; x++) {
        if (guess === answers[x]) {
            return guessIsCorrect();
        }
        if (x === answers.length) {
            return guessIsWrong();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! This is an obvious gap in my JavaScript knowledge. But why do I need to return either function? Shouldn't I be able to just call it?

Comment: I reckon there are/will be cases where both functions can fire. By using `return` you stop the function at that point and will ignore the code that comes after. You could also use `break` after guessIsCorrect or guessIsWrong is called as that would exit the for loop.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. Thanks for the help!